# Unity randomiser generating results in a non-random gradient

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm using code from the tutorial series "make a game" by Sebastian Lague and so far everything has been easily adapted to the new versions of unity. However on [Episode 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7BL-lboRXo&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0ctd4dgE1F8g3uec4zKNRV0&index=10), I have become unstuck. I have adapted the code for the map generator to get it to compile in my version of unity, `2019.3.11f1`. However, the random map generation seems to bias towards lowest coordinated of the map.

My Gen results:

[image: My Gen]

What it should look like:

[[image: target[2]]

This code is the map generator script it is placed on an empty in the world and adds cubes as obstacles, provided with some prefabs.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform tilePrefab;
    public Vector2 mapSize;
    public int seed = 10;
    public Transform obstaclePrefab;
    public int obstacleCount = 10;



    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float outlinePercent;  // Cotrols scale of tiles 

    List<Coord> allTileCoords;
    Queue<Coord> shuffledTileCoords;

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateMap();
    }


    public void GenerateMap()
    {

        allTileCoords = new List<Coord>();
        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.y; y++)
            {
                allTileCoords.Add(new Coord(x, y)); //iterate through mapSize adding tiles
            }
        }
        shuffledTileCoords = new Queue<Coord>(Utility.ShuffleArray(allTileCoords.ToArray(), seed)); //shuffled array of tiles coords

        string holderName = "Generated Map";                 //Added for the editor script
        if (GameObject.Find(holderName))                     //Added for the editor script
        {                                                    //Added for the editor script
            DestroyImmediate(GameObject.Find(holderName));   //Added for the editor script
        }                                                    //Added for the editor script

        Transform mapHolder = new GameObject(holderName).transform; //This is only neccessary because of the editor script
        mapHolder.parent = transform; //This is only neccessary because of the editor script

        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.y; y++)
            {
                Vector3 tilePosition = relativeToSpacial(x, y); //converts grid x,y data to real spatial coords
                Transform newTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tilePosition, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * 90)) as Transform; //instantiates tile in loctaion from rel to spatial func with 90 rotation
                newTile.localScale = Vector3.one * (1 - outlinePercent); //scales down tiles to leave a outline
                newTile.parent = mapHolder;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < obstacleCount; i++)
        {
            Coord randomCoord = GetRandomCoord();
            Vector3 obstaclePosition = relativeToSpacial(randomCoord.x, randomCoord.y);
            Transform newObstacle = Instantiate(obstaclePrefab, obstaclePosition + Vector3.up * .5f, Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
            newObstacle.parent = mapHolder;
        }
    }

    Vector3 relativeToSpacial(int x, int y)
    {
        return new Vector3(-mapSize.x / 2 + .5f + x, 0, -mapSize.y / 2 + .5f + y);
    }


    public Coord GetRandomCoord()
    {
        Coord randomCoord = shuffledTileCoords.Dequeue();
        shuffledTileCoords.Enqueue(randomCoord);
        //print("|| " + randomCoord.x + " || " + randomCoord.y + " ||");
        return randomCoord;
    }

    public struct Coord
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Coord(int _x, int _y)
        {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code from `Utility.ShuffleArray` which is my custom function for shuffling arrays.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public static class Utility
{
    public static T[] ShuffleArray<T>(T[] array, int seed)
    {
        System.Random prng = new System.Random(seed);
        for (int i =0; i < array.Length -1; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = prng.Next(i, array.Length);
            T tempItem = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = array[i];
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you are shuffling the array in ShuffleArray, should you just be swapping elements? in which case, you are missing the `array[i] = tempItem`... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int randomIndex = prng.Next(i, array.Length);
```

You are incrementing the clamp on your rng in this line in your for loop, so it becomes increasingly bias to the end of the array, also I added code to do a swap of positions rather than duplicate of position try something like this

```
int randomIndex = prng.Next(0, array.Length);
T tempItem = array[randomIndex];
T tempItemTwo = array[i];
array[randomIndex] = array[i];
array[i] = tempItemTWo;
```

if that doesnt work also try:

```
int randomIndex = prng.Next(i, array.Length);
T tempItem = array[randomIndex];
T tempItemTwo = array[i];
array[randomIndex] = array[i];
array[i] = tempItemTWo;
```